# Remove columns that match

Tags: pyspark

With 2 pyspark dataframes

| id | myTimeStamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-01 05:00 |
| 1 | 2022-06-06 05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-01 05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-02 05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-03 05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-04 08:00 |
| 3 | 2022-06-02 05:00 |
| 3 | 2022-06-04 10:00 |

| myTimeToRemove |
| --- |
| 2022-06-01 05:00 |
| 2022-06-04 05:00 |

Need to remove the records from first dataframe that contains values on second dataframe by date (doesn't matter the time)

Expected dataframe:

| id | myTimeStamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-06 05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-02 05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-03 05:00 |
| 3 | 2022-06-02 05:00 |

I tried

```
fdcn_df = fdcn_df.join(holidays_df, fdcn_df['myTimeStamp'].cast('date') != holidays_df['myTimeToRemove'].cast('date'),"inner")
```

but no result

I was expecting

Expected dataframe:

| id | myTimeStamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-06 05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-02 05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-06-03 05:00 |
| 3 | 2022-06-02 05:00 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your data type of `myTimeStamp` and `myTimeToRemove`? Assuming it is a  `timestamp` column, you can use `leftanti` join:

```
fdcn_df.alias('a').join(
    holidays_df.alias('b'),
    on=func.to_date(func.col('a.myTimeStamp'))==func.to_date(func.col('b. myTimeToRemove')),
    how='leftanti'
).show(100, False)
```